# Formula for generating random four-digit numbers google docs

Tags: google-sheets

Recently, I've had a challenge

I need to google tables to generate a string of 4 digits, where each digit is unique and the difference between neighboring digits is not 1
I have tried to use and modify this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(""; UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(MID(TEXT(RANDBETWEEN(1000; 9999); "0000"); ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A4"))); 1)))))
```

But the problem with this formula is that the digits are not unique and the difference between neighboring digits is not taken into account
I also tried to modify this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN("", UNIQUE(MID(TEXT(RANDBETWEEN(1000, 9999), "0000"), ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A4"))), 1))))
```

It generates unique digits, but does not take into account the difference between adjacent digits and sometimes returns two-digit and three-digit numbers

An example of an appropriate numbers: `1682, 2468, 3146`

Is it possible to make a formula suitable for my conditions?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by `the difference between neighboring digits is not 1` on your case; is it the difference between the numbers before *and* after the generated number? To help us understand better, it would also be good if you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or a sample string of numbers that fits your conditions.

Comment: By `the difference between adjacent digits is not equal to 1` is meant that when a number with index [0] is subtracted from a number with index [1] modulo their difference must not be equal to 1

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what exactly you mean by `minimal reproducible example` in this question, given that I attached the formulas, described what was wrong with them, and gave an example of correct numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also try this one:

```
=reduce("",sequence(4),lambda(a,c,
let(seq,sequence(10,1,0),
filter,filter(seq,not(isnumber(find(seq,a))),(seq<>right(a,1)+1),(seq<>right(a,1)-1),(c>1)+(seq>0)),
choices,rows(filter),
a&index(filter,randbetween(1,choices)))))
```

**EDIT**

Above formula does not allow number to start with 1.

Please try the following:

```
=reduce("",sequence(4),lambda(a,c,
let(seq,sequence(10,1,0),
filter,filter(seq,not(isnumber(find(seq,a))),(abs(seq-right(a,1))>1)+(c=1),(c>1)+(seq>0)),
choices,rows(filter),
a&index(filter,randbetween(1,choices)))))
```

Here are some numbers generated with this second formula:

[image]

Comment: Please see updated formula - I missed that the original formula didn't allow numbers starting with 1 because right("",1) ->0 ! Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can try:

`=LET(R,LAMBDA(R,n,IF(0=SUMPRODUCT(1=ABS(MID(n,{1,2,3},1)-MID(n,{2,3,4},1))),n,R(R,JOIN(,SORTN(ROW(1:10)-1,4,,RANDARRAY(10),))))),IF(NOW(),R(R,JOIN(,SORTN(ROW(1:10)-1,4,,RANDARRAY(10),)))))`

This formula generates a random 4 digit number with unique digits where adjacent digits do not differ by 1.